# activity indicator not showing for CPU intensive task

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app which may occasionally perform considerable CPU processing.
The sequence of events would be:

1) Ask user some questions
2) start activity indicator
3) do the CPU intensive stuff
4) display result

However, when I run this, the activity indicator does not show at step 2 but only at step 4.  I believe it is because UI is not updated by OS.
Any ideas on how to resolve this ?

Comment: Can we see some code to further assist you?

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly tell the main thread to wait until completing an action.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startActivityIndicatorMethod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

or if that doesn't work you could try running it on a background thread:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startActivityIndicatorMethod) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: What is this based on? At best this is a complete guess. There is nothing to go one that suggests this will fix the problem.

Comment: I have had the same issue with activity indicators not starting and stopping when expected, even in low CPU intensive tasks. This fixed that issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the main queue for UI related things like this and the code above won't do that in Swift. In swift the correct way is to do this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
 //update UI 
 }
```

Comment: Tried it, but it does not work.  I understand it looks like the most logical thing to do.  The code is actually dispatched at point 4 in my original post, i.e. AFTER all the CPU calculations have been performed. Thank you anyway

Comment: Well then can you edit your original post with some code to show what you've tried?

Comment: if source_shop_rowid  > 0 && destination_shop_rowid > 0 {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        print ("A.dispatch issed")
                        self.activity_indicator.startAnimating()
                    }
                    go_calculate()
                }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I resolved this issue with a very simple elementary solution.

The original sequence of events was:
1) ask user questions
2) start activity indicator
3) do CPU intensive calculations
4) display results.

One of the suggestions was to dispatch async to update the UI.  This did not work because UI was updated only after all calculations were done.
So, to resolve matters I changed code as:

1) ask user questions
2) start activity indicator
3) dispatch async do CPU intensive calculations
4) display results.

Now the UI correctly shows the activity indicator busy at point 2